# React Native with TypeScript tfjs-models/universal-sentence-encoder error on model load

Tags: typescript, react-native, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to use tfjs-models/universal-sentence-encoder within a React Native app by following [these instructions](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/universal-sentence-encoder#readme). However, I get the following error when I try to load the model:

```
ERROR: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_universalSentenceEncoder.default.load'
```

Code:

```html
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
require('@tensorflow/tfjs');
const use = require('@tensorflow-models/universal-sentence-encoder');

export default function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("App is starting...")
    
    const init = async () => {
      // initialize state variables 
      // console.log("App is initializing services...")
      
      // Load the model.
      try {
        use.load().then((model: any) => {
          // Embed an array of sentences.
          const sentences = [
            'Hello.',
            'How are you?'
          ];
          model.embed(sentences).then((embeddings: any) => {
            // `embeddings` is a 2D tensor consisting of the 512-dimensional embeddings for each sentence.
            // So in this example `embeddings` has the shape [2, 512].
            embeddings.print(true /* verbose */);
          });
        });
      }
      catch (err) {
        console.log(`ERROR: ${err}`);
      }
    };
  }, []);
```

Package versions:

- react-native@0.63.3
- @tensorflow-models/universal-sentence-encoder@1.3.2
- @tensorflow/tfjs@3.6.0
- @tensorflow/tfjs-react-native@0.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer yudhiesh provided fixes the cited error but produces another. A couple more changes need to be made to the code, and @tensorflow/tfjs needs to be downgraded from 3.3.0 to 3.0.0 (following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66647388/how-can-i-solve-this-possible-unhandled-promise-rejection-error)).

Here's the updated code:

```html
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import "@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native";
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
import * as use from '@tensorflow-models/universal-sentence-encoder';

export default function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("App is starting...")
    
    const init = async () => {
      // initialize state variables 
      // console.log("App is initializing services...")
      
      await tf.ready();
      
      // Load the model.
      try {
        use.load().then((model: any) => {
          // Embed an array of sentences.
          const sentences = [
            'Hello.',
            'How are you?'
          ];
          model.embed(sentences).then((embeddings: any) => {
            // `embeddings` is a 2D tensor consisting of the 512-dimensional embeddings for each sentence.
            // So in this example `embeddings` has the shape [2, 512].
            embeddings.print(true /* verbose */);
          });
        });
      }
      catch (err) {
        console.log(`ERROR: ${err}`);
      }
    };
  }, []);
```

Notice the import of `@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native`, the changes in how to import `@tensorflow/tfjs`, `@tensorflow-models/universal-sentence-encoder`, and the addition of calling `await tf.ready()` to ensure the tensorflow is initialized before attempting to load the use model.

This code produces the embeddings as expected when running on an iOS emulator, but it produces an embeddings vector full of `NaNs` when run on my physical iPhone. This is likely a separate issue, so consider this issue solved.

Comment: Problem solved, just needed to ensure all peer-dependencies of @tensorflow-models/universal-sentence-encoder, @tensorflow/tfjs-react-native, and @tensorflow/tfjswere met and correct

Answer (score 1):

I think it is to do with the way you are importing the universal-sentence-encoder, try this instead:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import * as use from '@tensorflow-models/universal-sentence-encoder';

export default function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("App is starting...")
    
    const init = async () => {
      // initialize state variables 
      // console.log("App is initializing services...")
      
      // Load the model.
      try {
        use.load().then((model: any) => {
          // Embed an array of sentences.
          const sentences = [
            'Hello.',
            'How are you?'
          ];
          model.embed(sentences).then((embeddings: any) => {
            // `embeddings` is a 2D tensor consisting of the 512-dimensional embeddings for each sentence.
            // So in this example `embeddings` has the shape [2, 512].
            embeddings.print(true /* verbose */);
          });
        });
      }
      catch (err) {
        console.log(`ERROR: ${err}`);
      }
    };
  }, []);
```